# in wordpress, how do I add tags to the divs Class

Tags: css, wordpress, codex

I want to add the post tags into its div class so I can add specific CSS for different types of tags.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you show the resultant html you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to output the tag name(s) of the article being viewed into a div, do that :

```
<div class="
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ' '; 
  }
}
?>
">
...
</div>
```

If you want to output the tag name that's being display (let's say the tag's page), do that :

```
<div class="<? echo single_tag_title(); ?>">
.....
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with mrtsherman, this question is vague, but if your wanting to name a class you would simply do something like

```
<div class="the-name-you-want">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass in argument on single_tag_title tag.

```
single_tag_title("<div class="header">");
```

Its perfectly works on my site.